# Swift, Slim Controller's Codes When Using TableView or CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I learned from Objc - issue 1, Lighter View Controllers which writen in Objective-C, so I write a swift version but I found a problem and I don't know how to explain this.

```
func setUpTableView() {
    let items = datas

    let configuarion: (_ cell: UITableViewCell, _ item: AnyObject) -> () = { cell,item in
        if let str = item as? String {
            cell.textLabel?.text = str
        }
    }

    let dataSource = ArrayDataSource(aItems: items as Array<AnyObject>, aCellIdentifier: "Cell", aConfigurationBlock: configuarion)
    tableView.dataSource = dataSource
}
```

I declear the variable 'dataSource' in the function, It has no effects, but when I declear it as a global variable, It works. I don't know what's the difference between these two methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your `ArrayDataSource` as controller's property. In your code `dataSource` will be deinit after end of function execution